# How to select the current item to delete it from an array in Swift using Realm

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

So, I have tried looking ALL over the internet and StackOverflow to find an answer, but I'm not sure what to even look for, so the answer may already have been shared. So I'm sorry in advance, as I am a noob. However, I still need help. (please!) I've got an app I'm working on with a  tableview full of parts, with a details part page that gives details of the part (Part name, part number, description, etc.)

I have a delete button at the end of the page, and when you click it, it asks you if you want to delete, are you sure? If the user says yes, then the part deletes, but the delete
only deleted the LAST item from the tableview, the most recently added. Which I know, is because I've called the following function:

```
    func deletePart() {
        if let partToDelete = getPartsArray().last {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(partToDelete)
            }
        }
```

with 'getPartsArray().**last**'

I'm trying to see how I can get the CURRENT selected part in the tableview to be deleted. Right now, I could have the second part from the top selected, and if I click THAT part's delete button, it will always delete the last part from the tableview.

Here's the code for the getPartsArray function:

```
    func getPartsArray() -> [PartInfo] {
        return getAllParts().map { $0 }
    }
```

I (noobishly) have already tried: with 'getPartsArray().**current**' and apparently that's not a thing lol.

I was also thinking, since I'm using REALM / Mongo DB, I could find the part by it's ID? and then delete it? but I'm not sure how to find the current select part's id either.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: here is my TableView Code:

```
//
//  ViewAllPartsViewController.swift
//  PartKart
//
//  Created by Kiarra Julien on 10/20/21.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewAllPartsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CurrencyFormatter  {
    
    private var brain = PartKartBrain()
    
    private var parts = [PartInfo]()
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBAction func returnHome() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "DemoTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DemoTableViewCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        parts = brain.getPartsArray()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        parts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DemoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoTableViewCell
        
        cell.partNameLabel.text = parts[indexPath.row].partName
        
        // Convert string value to double
        cell.partCostLabel.text = formatCurrency(value: parts[indexPath.row].partCost)
        //        String(format: "$%.2f", parts[indexPath.row].partCost)
        cell.purchaseDateLabel.text = parts[indexPath.row].purchaseDate
        // cell.textLabel?.text = parts[indexPath.row].partName
        // cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0countTotalParts()
        // cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPartDetails", sender: parts[indexPath.row])
    }
    
    // MARK: - Navigation
    
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let viewcontroller = segue.destination as? PartDetailsViewController {
            viewcontroller.part = sender as? PartInfo
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

and here's where I call delete part:

```
class PartDetailsViewController: UIViewController, CurrencyFormatter {
    
    //Store Information Labels
    @IBOutlet weak var storeNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var storeNumLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var storeAddrLabel: UILabel!
    
    //Part Information Labels
    @IBOutlet weak var partNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var partNumLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var partDescLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var partCostLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var partQtyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var purchaseDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hasWarrantySwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var warrantyLengthLabel: UILabel!
    
    //Mechanic Information Labels
    @IBOutlet weak var mechanicNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mechanicNumLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mechanicAddrLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var laborCostLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var serviceDateLabel: UILabel!
    
    var part: PartInfo?
    let brain = PartKartBrain()
    
    @IBAction func deletePartBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        // Declare Alert message
                let dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this part?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                // Create OK button with action handler
                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                     print("Ok button tapped")
                    // I CALL DELETE PART RIGHT HEREEE!
                    self.brain.deletePart()
                    
                    // delay and then dismiss the page
                    let delayInSeconds = 0.5
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { [unowned self] in
                        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
                
                // Create Cancel button with action handlder
                let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
                    print("Cancel button tapped")
                }
                
                //Add OK and Cancel button to dialog message
                dialogMessage.addAction(ok)
                dialogMessage.addAction(cancel)
                
                // Present dialog message to user
                self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
 
        
        title = part?.partName
        
        //Set the Store Info Labels Equal to actual data
        storeNameLabel.text = part?.partName
        storeNumLabel.text = part?.storeNumber
        storeAddrLabel.text = part?.storeAddress // < ---- The address is cut off the screen!
        
        //Set the Part Info Labels Equal to actual data
        partNameLabel.text = part?.partName
        partNumLabel.text = part?.partNumber
        partDescLabel.text = part?.partDescription
        
        if let partCost = part?.partCost {
            partCostLabel.text = formatCurrency(value: partCost)
        }
        
        if let partQty = part?.partQuantity {
            partQtyLabel.text = String(partQty)
        }
        
        purchaseDateLabel.text = part?.purchaseDate
        
        //If there's no warranty, display 'N/A' instead
        if part?.hasWarranty == true {
                hasWarrantySwitch.isOn = true
                warrantyLengthLabel.text = part?.warrantyLength
              } else {
                hasWarrantySwitch.isOn = false
                warrantyLengthLabel.text = "N/A"
              }
        
        //Set the Mechanic Info Labels Equal to actual data
        mechanicNameLabel.text = part?.mechanicName
        mechanicNumLabel.text = part?.mechanicNumber
        mechanicAddrLabel.text = part?.mechanicAddress
        //laborCostLabel.text = part?.laborCost
  
        if let laborCost = part?.laborCost {
            laborCostLabel.text = formatCurrency(value: laborCost)
        }
        
        serviceDateLabel.text = part?.serviceDate
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show us more of your code, in particular, your view with the 
tableview and where you call deletePart().

Comment: @workingdog okay, I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me state the question back to you

> "How to I delete a selected row from my tableview"?

If that's the question let be provide a boiled down answer

First, don't do this when working with Realm

```
return getAllParts().map { $0 }
```

Realm objects are lazily loaded into a Results object. As soon as you run them against a high level function like map, reduce etc (storing them in an Array), they ALL get loaded into memory and if you have a large dataset, that will overwhelm the device. Additionally if you have sorting etc, your objects will get out of sync with the underlying Realm data.

Your best bet is to leverage Realm Results as your tableView dataSource - it behaves much like an array.

So here's a viewController class that has a parts Results object as a tableView datasource

```
class InStockVC: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var partsNotificationToken: NotificationToken!
    var partsResults: Results<PartsClass>! //the tableView dataSource
```

Assume the user taps or selects row #2 and then taps or clicks 'Delete'

```
//pseudocode    
let selectedRow = tableView.selectedRow 
let part = partResults[selectedRow]
try! realm.write {
   realm.delete(part)
}
```

The above code determines which row in the table was selected, gets the part object from Results and then tells Realm to delete it.

As soon as that object is deleted from Realm, the partsResults object *reflects that change* and the object is automagically removed! The only thing you need to do is to reflect that change in the UI.

There are many ways of handling that with animations and so forth but to keep it simple, lets just reload the tableView so the deleted row is no longer displayed.

Note in the above code, there's also a `var partsNotificationToken: NotificationToken!`, that token is an observer of the results object - when something in the underlying data changes, the results object changes as well and the notification token fires an observer action to handle that change. Here's an example observer

```
self.partsNotificationToken = self.partsResults.observe { changes in
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
        self.tableView.reloadData() //update the tableview after data is initially loaded

    case .update(_, _, _, _):
        self.tableView.reloadData() //update the tableView after changes
```